# Chip Enable CE0 or CE01 not working with spidev

Tags: spi, pigpio, device-tree

I have enabled SPI via raspi-config and I can see /dev/spidev0.0 and /dev/spidev0.1. I can successfully execute the spidev_test.c (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/spi/spidev_test.c) echo test, but I cannot see any activity on the Chip Enable pins. I have tested with spidev0.0 and spidev0.1 both, but the corresponding CE pin is always high, and nothing is happening during the transfer operation. I think the driver should drive the CE pin automatically? I also tried to configure cs_change in the spi_ioc_transfer struct, but that didn't have any effect:

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
    .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
    .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
    .len = len,
    .delay_usecs = delay,
    .speed_hz = speed,
    .bits_per_word = bits,
    .cs_change = false, // No effect if true or false
};
```

I also noticed that the configured maximum speed in spidev_test.c doesn't match with the actual speed of the clock signal (measured using a logic analyzer).

However, Chip Enable pins seem to work automatically with pigpio + python:

```
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()
device = pi.spi_open(0, 500000, 0)
n, d = pi.spi_xfer(device, [0xff])
pi.spi_close(device)
pi.stop()
```

Also I noticed that with pigpio the speed selection works and the clock frequency matches with the configured value.

I tried this on Raspberry Pi 3 and 4 after a clean install of the latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite. What I'm missing here? I didn't try to configure CE/CS pin to some other GPIO, since I assume that this default configuration should work pretty much out-of-the-box after enabling SPI.

Comment: I don't see any code that would actually do anything.

Comment: The file spidev_test.c I was talking about is this one: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/spi/spidev_test.c

Comment: You posted python code in your question which would write 1 byte (and ignore the result). If you want an answer post some simple code to demonstrate your problem and test results. You haven't even detailed what is connected - SPI won't do anything without hardware.

Comment: Yes, and that python code works fine for testing if something happens on the CE pin, as there should. I didn't have anything connected, except for a logic analyzer. I was going to add screenshots from that, but apparently the CE pin is working today with the spidev_test.c also, at least for now. Not sure what was the issue, since I tested this using two different Raspberry Pis, and there was nothing happening on the CE pin. They were just always high.